# There are two date fields on an Object say Date1 & Date2,Now I want to Write a SOQL Query in SOQL Editor to fetch all the Object records

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

There are two date fields on an Object say Date1 & Date2, Now I want to Write a SOQL Query in SOQL Editor to fetch all the Object records where Date 2 is Greater than Date 1.
how you will do this using SOQL only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is we can create a Boolean/checkbox formula field on that objects which has below condition Date2_c > Date1_c

Then query the records where this formula field is true
i.e

SELECT Date1,date2 FROM object WHERE Date2_c >Date1_c